# Custom-Webclient Spock test throws unwanted NullPointerException in GET call

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, groovy, spock

Using the custom WebClient below:

```java
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component
public class TransitApiClient {

    private final TransitApiClientProperties transitApiClientProperties;

    private final WebClient transitApiWebClient;

    private final OAuth2CustomClient oAuth2CustomClient;

    public ResponseEntity<Void> isOfficeOfTransitValidAndNational(String officeId){
        try {
            final String url = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(transitApiClientProperties.getFindOfficeOfTransit())
                    .queryParam("codelistKey", "CL173")
                    .queryParam("itemCode", officeId)
                    .build()
                    .toUriString();

            return transitApiWebClient.get()
                    .uri(url)
                    .header(AUTHORIZATION, getAccessTokenHeaderValue(oAuth2CustomClient.getJwtToken()))
                    .retrieve()
                    .onStatus(status -> status.value() == HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT.value(),
                            clientResponse -> Mono.error( new InvalidOfficeException(null,
                                    "Invalid Office exception occurred while invoking :" + transitApiClientProperties.getFindOfficeOfTransit() + officeId)))
                    .toBodilessEntity()
                    .block();

        } catch (WebClientResponseException webClientResponseException) {
            log.error("Technical exception occurred while invoking :" + transitApiClientProperties.getFindOfficeOfTransit(), webClientResponseException);
            throw new TechnicalErrorException(null, "Technical exception occurred while trying to find " + transitApiClientProperties.getFindOfficeOfTransit(), webClientResponseException);
        }
    }
```

with its intended usage to hit an endpoint, and check if it returns a 200 code with a body or 204 NoContent code, and react accordingly with some custom exceptions.

I've implemented the groovy-spock test below :

```
class TransitApiClientSpec extends Specification {

    private WebClient transitApiWebClient
    private TransitApiClient transitApiClient
    private OAuth2CustomClient oAuth2CustomClient
    private TransitApiClientProperties transitApiClientProperties
    private RequestBodyUriSpec requestBodyUriSpec
    private RequestHeadersSpec requestHeadersSpec
    private RequestBodySpec requestBodySpec
    private ResponseSpec responseSpec
    private RequestHeadersUriSpec requestHeadersUriSpec

    def setup() {
        transitApiClientProperties = new TransitApiClientProperties()
        transitApiClientProperties.setServiceUrl("https://test-url")
        transitApiClientProperties.setFindOfficeOfTransit("/transit?")
        transitApiClientProperties.setUsername("username")
        transitApiClientProperties.setPassword("password")
        transitApiClientProperties.setAuthorizationGrantType("grantType")
        transitApiClientProperties.setClientId("clientId")
        transitApiClientProperties.setClientSecret("clientSecret")

        oAuth2CustomClient = Stub(OAuth2CustomClient)
        oAuth2CustomClient.getJwtToken() >> "token"
        transitApiWebClient = Mock(WebClient)
        requestHeadersSpec = Mock(RequestHeadersSpec)
        responseSpec = Mock(ResponseSpec)
        requestHeadersUriSpec = Mock(RequestHeadersUriSpec)
        transitApiClient = new TransitApiClient(transitApiClientProperties, transitApiWebClient, oAuth2CustomClient)
    }

    def "request validation of OoTra and throw InvalidOfficeException"(){
        given :
        def officeId = "testId"
        def uri = UriComponentsBuilder
                .fromUriString(transitApiClientProperties.getFindOfficeOfTransit())
                .queryParam("codelistKey", "CL173")
                .queryParam("itemCode", officeId)
                .build()
                .toUriString()

        1 * transitApiWebClient.get() >> requestHeadersUriSpec
        1 * requestHeadersUriSpec.uri(uri) >> requestHeadersSpec
        1 * requestHeadersSpec.header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer token") >> requestHeadersSpec
        1 * requestHeadersSpec.retrieve() >> responseSpec
        1 * responseSpec.onStatus() >> Mono.error( new InvalidOfficeException(null,null) )

        when :
        def response = transitApiClient.isOfficeOfTransitValidAndNational(officeId)

        then :
        thrown(InvalidOfficeException)
    }
```

But instead of an `InvalidOfficeException` being thrown, a `java.lang.NullPointerException` is thrown.

It seems to be triggered when during the test run, the program calls the following :

```java
return transitApiWebClient.get()
     .uri(url)
     .header(AUTHORIZATION, getAccessTokenHeaderValue(oAuth2CustomClient.getJwtToken()))
     .retrieve()
     .onStatus(status -> status.value() == HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT.value(),
                            clientResponse -> Mono.error( new InvalidOfficeException(null,
                                    "Invalid Office exception occurred while invoking :" + transitApiClientProperties.getFindOfficeOfTransit() + officeId)))
     .toBodilessEntity()   <---------------------- **HERE**
     .block();
```

I understand that I haven't mocked its behavior but seems to me that some other mock hasn't been done correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I can only recommend not to mock `WebClient` calls, as the necessary steps are a pain to mock, as you have seen yourself, requiring a lot of intermediary mocks without actually adding much value. This basically repeats the implementation, thus locking it in, which is not a good thing.

What I usually do is to extract all code that interacts with `WebClient` into a client class, and only mock this class interactions in my code. From the looks of it this is what you are already doing with `TransitApiClient`. For these client classes, I would recommend testing them with `MockServer`, `WireMock`, or any of the other frameworks. This way you actually make sure that the correct request/responses are sent/received, and you don't have to awkwardly deal with the `WebClient` interface.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is indeed tedious and complicated so I will probably shift my focus to another approach as you suggest.