# How to mock Spring WebClient call and stub some data while writing integration tests in Spock Frameowork

Tags: java, spring-webflux, spock

I am writing integration tests in spock framework for spring web flux application and we are using WebClient to make external api call. How can I mock WebClient and stub data to WebClient calls?

I am using RequestSpecification class to make api calls in integration tests.

Comment: You can use https://wiremock.org or https://www.mock-server.com to create stubs

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75304240/16358266

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this problem by using below code:

```
WebClient webClient

WebClient.RequestBodyUriSpec requestBodyUriSpec = 
Mock(WebClient.RequestBodyUriSpec)
WebClient.ResponseSpec responseSpec = Mock(WebClient.ResponseSpec)
```

inside test methods:

```
webClient.get() >> requestBodyUriSpec
webClient.post() >> requestBodyUriSpec
requestBodyUriSpec.body(_, _) >> requestBodyUriSpec
requestBodyUriSpec.uri(_) >> requestBodyUriSpec
requestBodyUriSpec.headers(_) >> requestBodyUriSpec
requestBodyUriSpec.retrieve() >> responseSpec
responseSpec.onStatus(_, _) >> responseSpec
responseSpec.bodyToMono(_) >>> {response objects to be mocked}
```